# how to resolve this error"An error occurred while trying to authenticate the package: 397613980.itmsp"? I am getting when loading my application

Tags: iphone

I have no idea why I am getting this error while adding my iPhone application with application loader:

An error occurred while trying to authenticate the package: 397613980.itmsp
An exception has occurred:javax/servlet/ServletContext
Could not connect to apple's web service

I have no idea what this errors are about? n what the hack java error doing here? any one with idea please help me?????

Comment: please go updated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902523/what-could-be-the-reason-for-the-error-please-see-detail-showing-image-of-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it seems that Apple severs are down.  Patience is a virtue… Try again later

Comment: post some more details about your build

Comment: More details like? its an utility application, I tested it on iTouch ios 4.1 working perfectly on iTouch and while I build the target it was fine with some warnings.....is warning causing this error?

Comment: post your relevant build settings and warnings

Comment: I am using my distribution provisioning profile and certificate, that part of uploadig is correct because I followed step by step process as documented on apple website.

Comment: Warning I am getting is like: "setImage is deprecated", warning: 'removeObjectsFromIndices:numIndices:' is deprecated, warning: class 'XMLReader' does not implement the 'NSXMLParserDelegate' protocol

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I had mistakenly submitted the app signed with an Ad Hoc provisioning profile instead of the App Store provisioning profile.