# What could be the reason for the error? Please see detail showing image of error

Tags: iphone

[image]

I am keep getting this error while uploading..I have no idea what this error are and how to resolve them...my build was successful(there are some warnings) my application is tested on iOS 4.1...any help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Superuser might be a better place for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Apple's servers may be having issues this weekend. I got a similar error. You should check iTunesConnect to see if the binary was uploaded, and perhaps send email to ITC support confirming.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well and was able to get around it by using Fink.
Basically, the issue was that Application Loader.app was expecting to find servlet.jar in my classpath & by not finding it, was throwing a Java error.  I tried with both the iOS 4.1 version of Xcode & Application Loader.app and the iOS 4.2 versions.

Solution:

- Download [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) & install.
- fire up Terminal.app
- `fink install jakarta-servletapi`
- quit Terminal.app & relaunch it (it should automatically update your shell)
- `cd /Developer/Applications/Utilities/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/` (assuming you have installed the dev tools to the standard location)
- `./Application\ Loader`
- smile

This is what worked for me, hope it helps?  You can probably achieve the same thing using other tools (such as DarwinPorts?), but I have chosen Fink given that's what I first picked years ago...  :)

Answer (score 1):

The local installation of XCode seems to be broken. Uploading the file from an other system does not show any problems. 
I try to reinstall XCode and hope that fixes my problem.

Comment: This should be posted as comment not answer. Isn't it ?

Comment: This is not an answer. While re installing can fix some problems, it more useful to know the nature of the problem is that way it can be corrected